# What would be a framework for shell migration?

Tags: shell

I am trying to migrate from bash to fish but face many compatibility issues and broken commands.

What would be a framework of steps to follow to realize seamless shell migration? Also what should I pay attention to when downloading new programs when using a shell other than bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fish is not bash or POSIX shell compatible.

That means the scripting language it uses is a different one, and so it can't directly run bash or sh script.

What that means is that, when someone tells you to "run this command in your shell", you either need to get a fish-compatible version, translate it yourself or open a bash session and run it there.

Which of those makes the most sense depends on the context. Is it just something to e.g. install some packages? That'll typically be easy to translate (very simple things like `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` are even compatible), but it also won't really hurt to run it in a bash session.

Now, when it comes to "downloading new programs", there are two cases:

Either the program is just something you *run*. Like you need to "execute cargo" or "run nvim". In that case there's no problem because the program is simply run by whatever interpreter it needs, no matter if it's a shell script or a python script or a compiled rust or go or c++ program. You run it, the operating system figures out how (by reading the `#!` line at the top for scripts), and done.

Or the program is a shell script that you need to `source`. This is the case if the documentation tells you to "Put `source nvm` in your ~/.bashrc" (also often spelt as `. nvm`, with that hard to see leading dot). In those cases, you'll have to find a fish-compatible version of it or alternative to it, or you'll have to resort to things that allow modifying the fish environment from a bash script like [bass](https://github.com/edc/bass) or [replay](https://github.com/jorgebucaran/replay.fish).

In my experience, the latter has become rarer as projects gain fish support. For instance when python tells you to "Source venv/bin/activate to activate the environment", you would simply source venv/bin/activate.fish because python's venv module ships with fish support out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

The fish shell is not POSIX shell  / Bourne shell compatible and differs in many aspects. Shell scripts mostly use sh or bash, so you have to pay attention that the right interpreter is chosen at the beginning if the script. The same goes for many shell-based solutions here at unix.stackexchange.com.

It is advisable to read  https://fishshell.com/docs/current/fish_for_bash_users.html for the differences.